# Trying to make a new column conditional on whether other columns are empty

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset which is like this:

```
new_fish old_fish 
1        2
         4
3
```

And I want to make a column called status, where if new_fish is empty call it dead, and if old_fish is empty call it born, and if neither are empty call it alive.

I would want it to look like this:

```
new_fish old_fish status
1        2        alive
         4        dead
3                 born
```

I've tried the following code in sas,

```
data diff_withclass;
set diff;
if missing(new_fish) then status= 'dead';
if missing(old_fish) then status= 'born';
else status = 'alive';
run;
```

However, this doesn't work. It just sets status to alive.

ANy suggestions would be great.

Comment: You are missing an ELSE.

Comment: Are you coding Conway's cellular automaton *Life* ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `else if`. The second `if` statement is overwriting the first.

```
data diff_withclass;
    set diff;

    if missing(new_fish) then status= 'dead';
        else if missing(old_fish) then status= 'born';
            else status = 'alive';
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful construction is `select`, when you're choosing one of a list of options.  Sometimes you `select` a varialbe:

```
select(var);
  when (1) do something;  *if var=1 then ... ;
  when (2) do something;  *else if var=2 then ... ;
  otherwise do something; *else ... ;
end;
```

However, it can be used alone also, as in your case.

```
data diff_withclass;
  set diff;
  length status $5;
  select;
    when (missing(new_fish)) status= 'dead';
    when (missing(old_fish)) status= 'born';
    otherwise status = 'alive'; 
  end;
run;
```

Another useful construction is the `ifc` function.  This works like Excel's `if`, in that it takes an argument that is a boolean (so, the "if" part), if that is true it returns the second argument, and if it is false it returns the third argument.  Here we can nest two of them to get your result.

```
data diff_ifc;
  set diff;
  length status $5;
  status = ifc(missing(new_fish),'dead',ifc(missing(old_fish),'born','alive'));
run;
```

Finally, there is the good old "boolean arithmetic" solution.  Here we create a numeric, and you can then turn that into a character if you prefer, or just use a user-defined format, which is really the optimal way to handle this anyway.  This takes advantage of the fact that "true" evaluates to 1 and "false" to 0 in SAS, so we just add up the values, and arbitrarily call Dead the 2 and Born the 1 (could do the opposite, or even have Dead=-1, Born=1, Alive=0, by multiplying by -1 for Dead).

```
proc format;
  value statusf
  0 = 'Alive'
  1 = 'Born'
  2 = 'Dead'
  ;
quit;
data diff_bool;
  set diff;
  status = missing(new_fish)*2 + missing(old_fish);
  format status statusf.;
run;
```